# Connecting slave to a jenkins master

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

I tried to connect slave to jenkins master through java web start but my efforts failed in the end.

I executed java -jar (jar file) (url) to connect and got the following errors.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:321)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:210)
```

Please help. Both Master and Slave use Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: This can be anything that prevents you from connecting. Firewalls, master not running, URL can not be resolved, wrong IP in the hosts files and many, many more.

Answer (score -6):

First of all, SO is not bug tracker for Jenkins project nor developers.

The Jenkins JIRA is located here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Secondly, in the wiki pages:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

contains pretty sufficient information that might guide you to fix. Probobly not permanent, but at least temporary.

For your comfort, here is the first link that fits the stack trace:

> Check that the JNLP port is opened if you are using a firewall on your server. You can configure its value in Jenkins configuration. By default it is set to use a random port.

Cheers and good luck!